# Configuring Data Table from Highcharts Basic Column Chart

Tags: charts, highcharts, data-visualization

I am working with Highcharts and looking to create a data table from the Basic Column chart (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic) with the following functionality:

1. Flip the row and columns so that the x-axis of the bar chart is the column headers in the data table. So in the example link above, when I click on "View Data Table", I want to take the x-axis from the chart and make it the column headers in the data table.
2. Be able to sort the columns.

I see examples online of how to do that by building the table first and then creating the chart from the table. But isn't this possible the other way around - creating the chart first and then just configuring the data table to have the above functionality?

Or do you have to create the table first, and then create the chart from that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the right approach to your requirements will be creating a custom `HTML table` and parsing data from it into the chart, just like here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.table